# Shipping Report - Distinct Order with Two Dates - Status Missing from Table THEN

Tags: sql, t-sql, distinct

Links to the tables in the screenshot can be found at the link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAX85i7QE4zr1S-zr-_Lo00VUnIkE02XWo

**First Issue:**

Normally this table (See Load Tracking Table) would have a Field in Check Call Name that is "Pickup - Actual" signalling that this has been picked up. However in certain circumstances the `CheckCallName` will bypass the pickup and move to Delivered status. In cases like this I want to pull the query to treat the "Delivered" status in the same manner that Pickup Actual was being used.

Said another way, where `kpo.loadtracking` does not have Pickup - Actual in the Check Call Name field for any one order, I want to pull the Check Call Name for Delivered and the `KeypointStatusDate`.

**Second Issue:**

The `DISTINCT` clause does not work perfectly in my case, as an order can have the Pickup - Actual status updated multiple times. Here, we should take the oldest Keypoint Status Date. I've tried to use the `MIN(KeypointStatusDate)` and grouping by Order ID but I'm getting the following message

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Column 'KPO.LOAD.LoadId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The code I have currently is below. I'm new to SQL (about a week in) so apologies if this is simple.

```
SELECT          
    Distinct LOAD.LoadNumber
    ,LOAD.LoadId            
    ,CustomerName           
    ,OrderStatus            
    ,CheckCallName      
    ,PickedUpOn         
    ,LoadTracking.KeypointStatusDate        
    ,LOAD.OriginEarliest            
    ,LOAD.DestinationEarliest           
    ,CustomerRate           
    ,CarrierCost            
    ,Miles
FROM KPO.LOAD   
    Inner JOIN kpo.LoadExtension ON LOAD.LoadId = LoadExtension.LoadId          
    Inner JOIN kpo.Customer ON customer.CustomerId = LOAD.CustomerID            
    Inner JOIN kpo.LoadTracking ON LoadTracking.LoadId = LOAD.LoadId            
WHERE           
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), LoadTracking.KeypointStatusDate) = - 2
        AND OrderStatus <> 'VOID'
        AND CheckCallName = 'Pickup - Actual'
ORDER BY CustomerName, LoadNumber, LoadTracking.KeypointStatusDate
```

**Load Tracking Table with Question Inside:**

[image: Load Tracking Table with Question Inside]

**Data Result from Query:**

[image: Data Result from Query]

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot execute queries on your images. We need table(s) and data. Please provide queries to create the relevant table(s) and insert the sample data instead of (or in addition to) stories and images. In general you should provide us the tools to reproduce the issue in our environment `:-)`

Comment: Thanks, Ronen. I've added a link with the data tables shown in the screenshots!

Comment: Hi Cole, seems like you did not shared the permission to use the file and I get error that I must use your email. More inportant is that seems like this file is excel file Tables.xlsx which is not relevant since you want a solution in t-sql. I asked you to provide queries to create the tables and insert data and not excel file. What can I do with the excel?!? Please use simple txt file and provide queries and make sure that we can download the file without register to any external website. `Regards,`